# Counting Rhythms

Tags: code-golf, music

### The Narrative

You are a bad musician. You never bothered to learn how to count rhythms. To remedy this shortcoming, you decide to write a program that will tell you how to count in any given time signature. You are still a bad musician, but you can at least pretend that you can count rhythms.

### The Objective

Given a time signature, output a possible counting pattern for said time signature.

**For those who don't know musical terms:**
A [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_(music)) is, essentially, a group of notes, useful for organizing music and making sure the musicians don't lose their place in the music.
A [time signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature) is a set of numbers in a piece of music which tells you how many beats are in a measure, and which note-length is the beat. For example, a `3/4` time signature tells you that each measure has `3` beats, and the quarter note (`4`) is the beat. An `11/16` T.S. tells you that there are `11` sixteenth note beats (`16`) in one measure.
A [counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_(music)) pattern is a way to verbally express the division of a measure. For example, a song in `3/4` can simply be counted as `"1 2 3"`. `11/16` can be counted as `"1 la li 2 e & a 3 e & a"` (this is more intuitive than counting to 11; I will define this later)
*It's important to note that the bottom number of almost all T.S.'s are a power of 2. For this challenge, we will ignore irrational T.S.'s. We will also not look at T.S.'s with a beat greater than 16.*

**How to Generate a Counting Pattern:**
Time signatures with a `X/1`, `X/2`, or `X/4` can simply be counted with numbers (`4/2` can be counted as `"1 2 3 4"`).
T.S.'s with a `X/8` or `X/16` are a bit more tricky. These can be counted by grouping beats together to form larger beats (`6/8`, despite having `6` 'beats', is very often treated as `2` beats with a triplet subdivision). **For this challenge, beats should be grouped in groups of `1`(`"1"`), `2`(`"1 &"`), `3`(`"1 la li"`), or `4`(`"1 e & a"`)**
For `X/8`, groups of `3` should be prioritized over `2`, but `1` should be avoided if possible. (For `7/8`, even though `3+3+1` prioritizes `3`'s, `3+2+2` is better because it avoids `1`)
For `X/16`, groups of `3` should be prioritized over `4`, but `2` and `1` should be avoided if possible. (For `11/16`, even though `3+3+3+2` prioritizes `3`'s, `3+4+4` is better because it avoids `2`)
*It is important to note that the ordering of the groups is not important, i.e. `3+2` and `2+3` are both acceptable groupings of `5/8`. This would be important normally, but you are a bad musician.*
*Also note that T.S.'s 'larger' than `1/8` can be grouped entirely with `2`'s and `3`'s; T.S.'s 'larger' than `5/16` can be grouped entirely with `3`'s and `4`'s.*

Whew! What a mouthful!

### The Specs

**You will take a time signature as input.** this may be formatted within reason (use common sense!).
**You will output an acceptable counting pattern.** This will be a string of counts (`1`, `la`, `&`, etc.) separated by spaces. Your output should not include leading or trailing whitespace.
**Test Cases:**
*To clarify, the 'numerator' is a positive integer, and the 'denominator' is `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, or `16`.*
*Again, note that some T.S.'s have multiple valid outputs.*

```
"Input", "Output"
"1/1", "1"
"3/2", "1 2 3"
"4/4", "1 2 3 4"
"1/8", "1"
"10/8", "1 la li 2 la li 3 & 4 &"
"2/16", "1 &"
"5/16", "1 la li 2 &"
"29/16", "1 la li 2 la li 3 la li 4 la li 5 la li 6 la li 7 la li 8 e & a 9 e & a"

"Input", "Invalid Output"
"6/4", "1 la li 2 la li"
"7/8", "1 la li 2 la li 3"
"10/8", "1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &"
"12/16", "1 e & a 2 e & a 3 e & a"
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: For 10/8 is `1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 &` valid?

Comment: @ophact No, it avoids `1`'s, but `1 la li 2 la li 3 & 4 &` prioritizes `3`'s while still avoiding `1`'s. I've added this as a test case!

Comment: "_Your output should not include leading or trailing whitespace._" I assume a single trailing newline is allowed, or not either? A lot of programming languages add a trailing newline by default, and disallowing this doesn't add much to the core of the challenge anyway.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Trailing newlines are not allowed

Comment: @DeletedComment The `10/8` example is grouped as `3+3+2+2`… maybe you misread? 2 groups of 2 look like `”1 & 2 &”`, while 1 group of 4 looks like `”1 e & a”`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is a zero-indexed input allowed? So input would be `5/3` for 6/4 time

Comment: @jezza_99 Sure, I’ll allow that

Comment: Yet one more reason I never becase a good piano player.  Just curious; are there many (common?) pieces of music with an `11/16` time signature?

Comment: @MarkStewart Not really. It could be used for rhythm etudes. You'll probably find it in contemporary genres like mathcore and lo-fi, and maybe bebop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 46 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œṗi@€o⁸Ṁ;ṢƊɗÞ:5×6Œ?Ɗ}Ḣị““&“la li“e & a”Ė¹Ƈ€K€K
```

A full program that accepts the beats and the note-length and prints the result

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7p2c6PGpak/@occfDnQ3WD3cuOtZ1cvrheVamh6ebHZ1kf6yr9uGORQ93dz9qmANEakCck6iQkwmkUxXUFBIfNcw9Mu3QzmPtQEO8Qfj///9Glv8NzQA)**

#### How?

```
Œṗi@€o⁸Ṁ;ṢƊɗÞ:5×6Œ?Ɗ}Ḣị“...”Ė¹Ƈ€K€K - Main Link: beats, B; note-length L
Œṗ                                  - all integer partitions of B
                    }               - using L:
                   Ɗ                -   last three links as a monad - f(L):
                                                             e.g. 1,2,4,8,16
             :5                     -     integer divide by 5  -> 0,0,0,1,3
               ×6                   -     multiply by six      -> 0,0,0,6,18
                 Œ?                 -     shortest permutation of [1..N] which has that
                                            lexicographic 1-based-index in a list of all
                                            permutaions of [1..N]
                                                               -> [],[],[],[3,2,1],[3,4,2,1]
                                                                  (our ordering)
            Þ                       - sort (the partitions) by:
           ɗ                        -   last three links as a dyad - f(Partition, Ordering)
    €                               -     for each (run-length, R) in the partition:
  i@                                -       first 1-indexed index of R in Ordering or 0
     o⁸                             -       logical OR with the Partition (vectorises)
                                              (replaces 0s with the larger, original Rs)
          Ɗ                         -       last three links as a monad - f(X):
       Ṁ                            -         maximum of X
         Ṣ                          -         sorted X
        ;                           -         concatenate
                     Ḣ              - head
                       “...”        - ["", "&", "la li", "e & a"]
                      ị             - index into
                            Ė       - enumerate (i.e. [A, B, ...] -> [[1,A],[2,B],...])
                               €    - for each:
                             ¹Ƈ     -   keep truthy (i.e. drop the "" entries)
                                K€  - join each with spaces
                                  K - join with spaces
                                    - implicit print
```

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>372</s> <s>354</s> <s>308</s> <s>301</s> <s>299</s> <s>260</s> <s>240</s> <s>237</s> 233 bytes

```c
#define p!printf(" %d%s"+!i++,i,a
#define q(x,y,z)(j=n%3-z/4)|n<z?p[x]),~j:p[y])+p[y])-z;
*a[]={""," &"," la li"," e & a"};f(n,d,i,j){for(i=0;d<5&&n--;)p[0]);n+=d-8?0:q(j,1,4)for(n+=d<16?0:n<2?p[0])-n:q(j=j?j+3:1,3,8)n>0;n-=3)p[2]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc/LboMwEAXQPV/huALZ9VjFQKIU4/IhiAXiUdlKXfKolEDpr1MTqQuazWh0dHVHU/P3up7np6bttG1Rv@lP2l46gpHf@GfMNpox0FB5f4kjucINBkqMsn7Mh5eEfttsyPviWlL4MWlf3ErK7pMP0nuuilKNGANGwTIOFTroZWlRgCo8yY5YaNwJQ8fu80S0CmWTbYPAci5pX4QllZaphu/zMD0SAwISugQXzMTOqc2i/B7kdkkokxsWpwJi2FP7FkrLVeyaItc0ze479FFpS6g3eh0RIKjsvy5ngjGVDmKI1pC4eysQrnYN4X@JQOzWsn2Q6PWBxF28af4F)

*-24 bytes thanks to ceilingcat*

*-46 bytes thanks to ceilingcat*

*-7 bytes thanks to ceilingcat*

*-2 bytes thanks to ceilingcat*

*-39 bytes thanks to both Juan Ignacio Díaz and ceilingcat*

*-20 bytes thanks to both Juan Ignacio Díaz and ceilingcat*

*-3 bytes thanks to ceilingcat*

*-4 bytes thanks to ceilingcat*

Comment: It breaks for `1/16`, `2/16`, and `3/16`... Everything else seems to be working fine though!

Comment: @Nilster fixed it

Comment: Very nice! Until it’s beaten (or proven faulty) I’m marking this correct!

Comment: @ceilingcat you're crazy. I couldn't even understand what I wrote and you're still golfing it

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 52 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
5‹iLëÅœΣ4LRIg·†3†Rsk{}θε…e&aN>©š®D'&‚®…ÿ…å´à)ćè]˜ðý?
```

Two separated inputs \$a\$ and \$b\$, where \$b\$ is the beat and \$a\$ are the amount of notes in the measure.
<sup>*†*</sup>If the input was as strict as the output, a trailing `` '/¡`© `` (+5 bytes) could be added and the `I` could be replaced with `®`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f9FHDzkyfw6sPtx6dfG6xiU@QZ/qh7Y8aFhgDcVBxdnXtuR3ntj5qWJaqluhnd2jl0YWH1rmoqz1qmHVoHVD08H4QsfTQlsMLNI@0H14Re3rO4Q2H99r//29oxmVkCQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXCoZX/TR817Mz0Obz6cOvRyecWm/gEHVqXfmj7o4YFxkAcVJxdXXtux7mtjxqWpaol@tkdWnl04aF1LupqjxpmHVoHFD28H0QsPbTl8ALNI@2HV9TWnp5zeMPhvfb/D22z/x8dbahjGKsTbaxjBCRNdEyApKGOBYg0AFNGOoZmQMoUQhlZQmgzsEJziEKwklgA) or <sup>*†*</sup>[try it online with strict input format](https://tio.run/##AW0Akv9vc2FiaWX//ycvwqFgwqk14oC5aUzDq8OFxZPOozRMUsKuZ8K34oCgM@KAoFJza3t9zrjOteKApmUmYU4@wqnFocKuRCcm4oCawq7igKbDv@KApsOlwrTDoCnEh8OoXcucw7DDvT///zE2LzI5).

`4LR®g·†3†R` could alternatively be `4L14S.I®gè` for the same byte-count: [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXCoZX/TR817Mz0Obz6cOvRyecWm/gYmgTreR5al354RXF2de25Hee2PmpYlqqW6Gd3aOXRhYfWuairPWqYdWgdUPTwfhCx9NCWwws0j7QfXlFbe3rO4Q2H99r/P7TN/n90tKGOYaxOtLGOEZA00TEBkoY6FiDSAEwZ6RiaASlTCGVkCaHNwArNIQrBSmIB).

**Explanation:**

```python
5‹i            # If the first (implicit) input is smaller than 5 (1, 2, or 4):
   L           #  Push a list in the range [1, second (implicit) input] 
ë              # Else (it's 8 or 16 instead):
 Åœ            #  Get all lists of positive integers that sum to the second
               #  (implicit) input
   Σ           #  Sort it by:
    4LR        #   Push list [4,3,2,1]
       I       #   Push the second input again
        g      #   Pop and push its length
         ·     #   Double it
          †    #   Filter that value to the front
           3†  #   Then filter 3 to the front
             R #   And then reverse the list
               #   (we now have [1,4,2,3] for input=8
               #   and [1,2,4,3] for input=16)
    s          #  Swap so the current list
     k         #  Get the index of each in this list (or -1 if higher)
      {        #  Sort that list from lowest to highest
   }θ          #  After the sort: leave the last list
               #  (so `Σ...}θ` acted as a maximum-by builtin)
 ε             #  Map that resulting list to:
  …e&a         #   Push string "e&a"
      N>       #   Push the 1-based map-index
        ©      #   Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
         š     #   Convert the string to a list, and append it: 
               #    ["e","&","a",index]
  ®            #   Push index `®` again
  D            #   And again, with a duplicate
   '&‚        '#   Pair it with "&"
  ®            #   And yet again
   …ÿ…å´à      #   Push dictionary string "ÿ la li",
               #   where the `ÿ` is replaced with this index
  )            #   Wrap all values into a list
   ć           #   Extract the head; the current list of the map
    è          #   Modular 0-based index those into the list
]              # Close both the map and if-else statement
 ˜             # Flatten the list of lists
  ðý           # Join it with a space delimiter
    ?          # Explicitly print it without trailing newline
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `…ÿ…å´à` is `"ÿ la li"`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>136</s> 135 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```python
def f(m,b,r='',i=1):
 while m:k=b<5or[m,3-(m<5)+(6<m<9)*b/9][m>2+b/8];m-=k;r+=' '+`i`+[' e & a',' la li',' &',''][-k];i+=1
 print r[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDtaoMwFP3vU1wYGF0iXWK0fmUvIkIrUxo0bZHC2NO7GFMts4X90JN7zsm5R68/t9PlzMbxq2mh9RSpySAQIlJQP3Pg@yT7BlTWibqILkOpSBh4qoh87MWFKlL/vd6lVak@Ga53SZWrQHT5gAUChA/ygEsEDbhwRARBf4ReTgdXv1BVBl2VSyyoA9dBnm8wlDSrxtajhPoA8AbUab2QMDsAg1ATjPCF0CN/GCEE7kz3k/U@XwZdg@lHc/HKmU6aN6il/VZydayrpeTFLSvTD6M/lYEbCyM0thbXVFtG84@matHKLftN4w29Nt5IJs00/rNgldIXgbrtPVh/0OR5ZrmnULqxzIseLOxlyox8WcjS/1khshhb3FtM7PZ0xvEX)

Takes input as `f(m,b)` where `m` is the numerator and `b` is the denominator

#### Explanation

```python
while m:
```

Loop while `m` > 0

```python
k=b<5or[m,3-(m<5)+(6<m<9)*b/9][m>2+b/8]
```

Determine the size of the next group. Essentially the logic is as follows:

- `b in [1,2,4]` => **1**
- `b == 8 and m == 4` => **2**
- `b == 16 and m in [7,8]` => **4**
- `(b == 8 and m <= 3) or (b == 16 and m <= 4)` => **m**
- otherwise => **3**

```python
m-=k;r+=' '+`i`+[' e & a',' la li',' &',''][-k];i+=1
```

Decrease `m` by the group size. Append the following to `r`: First a space, then the current group index, then the appropriate suffix based on the group size. Increment the group index

```python
print r[1:]
```

Output the constructed string, removing the leading space

Comment: [-1 byte by replacing `return` with `print`.](https://tio.run/##jVDtaoMwFP3vU1wYGF0iXWK0fmUvIkIrUxo0bZHC2NO7GFMts4X90JN7zsm5R68/t9PlzMbxq2mh9RSpySAQIlJQP3Pg@yT7BlTWibqILkOpSBh4qoh87MWFKlL/vd6lVak@Ga53SZWrQHT5gAUChA/ygEsEDbhwRARBf4ReTgdXv1BVBl2VSyyoA9dBnm8wlDSrxtajhPoA8AbUab2QMDsAg1ATjPCF0CN/GCEE7kz3k/U@XwZdg@lHc/HKmU6aN6il/VZydayrpeTFLSvTD6M/lYEbCyM0thbXVFtG84@matHKLftN4w29Nt5IJs00/rNgldIXgbrtPVh/0OR5ZrmnULqxzIseLOxlyox8WcjS/1khshhb3FtM7PZ0xvEX)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 70 bytes

```
ＮθＮη⪫Ｅ⊟Φ…⟦Ｅθ¹Ｅ÷⁺²θ³⁻³‹ι﹪±θ³Ｅ÷θ³⁺³‹ι﹪θ³⟧⊕÷η⁸⁼θΣι⁺⊕κ§⪪“/^e)R⁼0⁷Ｖⅉ8⮌✳”,ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY3BSsNAEIbvfYphD2UC46EWReip1BYiWgI9ioc1GczgZpNNdos@/bpJPATd087/z/dNWeu@bLWJMbdd8OfQvHOPLtutlnOd5qIX6/GpFYsvusOi7fAkxqf28F0aPtQpeB0bR7DJCMZvbv2jXKViLEwY8JbApWY7tmJTsCV45mFASUFbBdPimT@0Z5zX0vvrcTM@6f7T7pd6I8ht2XPD1nO1wGuCh8l6dEGbYQQuoUGZT03WJfiZwr3PbcVfeOmMeFTAsAZNBGsCo8GIIlCk0qJMDgUqy3Yx3q029/Hman4A) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input the time signature.

```
⟦Ｅθ¹Ｅ÷⁺²θ³⁻³‹ι﹪±θ³Ｅ÷θ³⁺³‹ι﹪θ³⟧
```

Try to create three beat patterns: all single beats, as many groups of three as possible with the rest two, and as many groups of three as possible with the rest four.

```
…...⊕÷η⁸
```

Only consider the first or first two patterns depending on the denominator.

```
Φ...⁼θΣι
```

Only keep those patters that actually sum to the whole bar. (This prevents e.g. `5/16` from trying to use groups of three and four).

```
⪫Ｅ⊟...⁺⊕κ§⪪...,ι
```

Take the last successful pattern and replace each group with its beat number and group suffix obtained by splitting the compressed string  `e & a,, &, la li`, finally joining the groups with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 56 bytes

```
5<[ɾ|Ṅµ1k½d⁰LǔJ3Jvḟs;tṘ¨2›:£`e&a`fJ¥:\&"¥«cb|«"ṄWḣi;]fṄ₴
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJUIiwiIiwiNTxbyb584bmEwrUxa8K9ZOKBsEzHlEozSnbhuJ9zO3ThuZjCqDLigLo6wqNgZSZhYGZKwqU6XFwmXCLCpcKrY2J8wqtcIuG5hFfhuKNpO11m4bmE4oK0IiwiIiwiMTZcbjI5Il0=)

Port of 05AB1E. Quite slow.